# How can I add apps from different regions?

Tags: google-account, apk, accounts

I want to install apps from another region (example [Nabobil](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nabobil.app)), but can't, because I have a different region on my phone. I'm using Google Pixel 2 running on Android 10 (latest Android version at the moment).

I don't find the app either on Aurora Store and Yalp Store.

What would be the simplest way to do this?
Preferably without having to go to a different "desktop".  (logging in the whole phone to a different account)

Comment: Have the solutions in the linked questions didn't work for you?

Comment: @Firelord The first question is about location, The second is about paid apps when paid apps is not supported in your country.

Comment: If you're okay with it, then the alternative is to use alternative markets and/or APK mirror sites such as [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/nabobil/no.nabobil.app). However, standard disclaimer for such alternative markets: we are not responsible for any malfunctions to the device if you proceed.

Comment: I've added another 2 dupe links, please also check them.

Comment: SOLUTION: I ran Google Play Store under an account from target region, confirmed with a credit card from that region, and added as a Google account on the device.

Comment: Practically I created a new Google account (Don't think how mattered), added it to the device and switched Google Play Store.  Then I clicked on a link for the app, and were prompted about region and credit card.